# JDBC, оптимизация кода

Tags: java, оптимизация, jdbc

Есть три метода, которые отличаются буквально в  пару строчек.
Можно как-то избежать дублирования кода?

```
@Override
public List<Employee> findAll()  {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_FIND_ALL);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Employee tempEmployee = convertRowToEmployee(rs);
            list.add(tempEmployee);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        dataSource.closeConnection(connection);
    }
    return list;
}

@Override
public List<Employee>  findByName(String name) {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_FIND_BY_NAME);
        statement.setString(1, name);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Employee tempEmployee = convertRowToEmployee(rs);
            list.add(tempEmployee);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        dataSource.closeConnection(connection);
    }
    return list;
}


@Override
public List<Employee> findAllAbsenceEmployeeByDate(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_FIND_ALL_ABSENCE_BY_DATE);
        statement.setDate(1, startDate);
        statement.setDate(2, endDate);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Employee tempEmployee = convertRowToEmployee(rs);
            list.add(tempEmployee);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        dataSource.closeConnection(connection);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Преобразование строк в объект вынес в отдельный метод  convertRowToEmployee(rs), соединение и закрытие вынес в отдельный класс DataSource

Answer (score 0):

Оптимизировать лучше не надо, так как потом в случае расширения (добавления новых фич) Вам придется заново все по полной программе тестировать плюс потеряете в читабельности кода.
Также у Вас в коде присутствует ошибка. Необходимо закрывать PreparedStatement и ResultSet. Рекомендую метод закрытия этих объектов также реализовать в DataSource как то так:

```
public void close(){
    if (conn != null){
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

    public void close(PreparedStatement ps){
    if (ps != null){
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void close(CallableStatement cs){
    if (cs != null){
        try {
            cs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void close(PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs){
    close(ps);
    if (rs != null){
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void close(CallableStatement cs, ResultSet rs){
    close(cs);
    if (rs != null){
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. получается мне надо будет вызывать два раза метод close?
dataSource.closeConnection(statement, rs)
dataSource.closeConnection(connection)
Еще прочитал что  при закрытии Statement автоматически закрываются все связанные с ним открытые объекты ResultSet. Т.е. достаточно закрыть statment?

Comment: @A.Grin да. В принципе если вы уверены что вам всегда после выполнения select надо закрывать соединение вы можете в свой close вставить закрытие Statement и ResultSet. Я не знаю надо ли закрывать ResultSet после закрытия Statement но не думаю что закрытие его если он не null вреда не принесет

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно избежать дублирования кода, причём разными способами. Судя по синтаксису ваших примеров, используется Java версии не ниже 8. В `Java 8` были введены возможности функционального подхода программирования, которые прекрасно подходят для решения Вашей задачи. Вот пример:

1. Создайте функциональный интерфейс

   ```
   @FunctionalInterface
   public interface ConsumerWithException<T> {
      void accept(T t) throws SQLException;
   }
   ```

   Можно бы было использовать готовый `java.util.function.Consumer`, но в `ps.setString` объявлено выбрасываемое исключение `SQLException`, а `java.util.function.Consumer` не объявляет никаких исключений в методе `accept`, поэтому приходится создавать свой интерфейс.
2. Создайте метод, выполняющий общие для всех 3-х вариантов задачи, и использующий `ConsumerWithException` для обработки специфического кода этих вариантов

   ```
   public List<Employee> findEmployees(String sql, ConsumerWithException<PreparedStatement> consumer) {
   PreparedStatement statement = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   try (
           Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()
   ) {
       statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
       consumer.accept(statement);//здесь выполняются специфиеческие действия
       rs = statement.executeQuery();
       List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
       while (rs.next()) {
           Employee tempEmployee = convertRowToEmployee(rs);
           list.add(tempEmployee);
       }
       return list;
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   } finally {
       try {
           if (rs != null && !rs.isClosed()) {
               rs.close();
           }
       } catch (SQLException ignored) {
       }
       try {
           if (statement != null && !statement.isClosed()) {
               statement.close();
           }
       } catch (SQLException ignored) {
       }
   }
   }
   ```

   Здесь я оперирую методами стандартного `javax.sql.DataSource`, в котором нет метода `closeConnection`. Возможно, и Вам тоже можно обойтись только стандартными методами `DataSource`, т.к. современные реализации источников данных обычно имеют всю нужную функциональность и не требуют расширения.
3. Вызов 3-х вариантов ваших методов

   ```
   //вместо метода findAll()
   List<Employee> all = findEmployees(SQL_FIND_ALL, (PreparedStatement ps) -> {});

   //вместо метода findByName(String name)
   String name = "John";
   List<Employee> byName = findEmployees(SQL_FIND_BY_NAME, (PreparedStatement ps) -> {
       ps.setString(1, name);
   });

   //вместо метода findAllAbsenceEmployeeByDate(Date startDate, Date endDate)
   Date startDate = Date.valueOf("2017-01-01");
   Date endDate = Date.valueOf("2017-02-01");
   List<Employee> absense = findEmployees(SQL_FIND_ALL_ABSENCE_BY_DATE, (PreparedStatement ps) -> {
       ps.setDate(1, startDate);
       ps.setDate(2, endDate);
   });
   ```